# How to set checkbox inside table cell with jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to set a checkbox inside the first cell of each row for given indexes.
How can I access the checkbox?
I have tried so far the following:

```
function checkLocationTable (colindexes,tablename) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tablename);
    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        if (colindexes.includes(i)) {
            $(this).find("td:eq(0) .checkbox").prop("checked", true);
        }
    }
}
```

`colindexes` is an array of ints, *e.g.*: `[1, 2, 3]`.

I have also tried:

```
function checkLocationTable(colindexes, tablename) {
    $("#" + tablename + " tr").each(function(index) {
        if ($.inArray(colindexes, index)) {
            $(this).find("td:eq(0) > checkbox").attr("checked", true);
        }
    });
}
```

The second example does not even enter inside the inner function.

Comment: is your checkbox having class "checkbox" or is it a typo in your javascript function here : 
 $(this).find("td:eq(0) .checkbox").prop("checked",true);

Comment: No there's no class nor id ..just a plain checkbox inside the first cell of the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do your selection on the row object instead of this:

```
function checkLocationTable (colindexes,tablename){
            var table = document.getElementById(tablename);
            for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
                if(colindexes.includes(i))
                {

                    $(row).find("td:first input:checkbox").prop("checked",true);

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you it worked.I have tried all combinations for the selector: "td:eq(0) >checkbox""..." ... .checkbox", " td:eq(0) checkbox".Nothing worked but this finally did it.

Comment: @user1913744, your inArray call is reversed, should be `$.inArray(index,colindexes)`. But your code is almost correct.

Comment: I will publish amended version of your try

Answer (score 1):

Based on your last try. Your code is almost correct. The order of the parameters in $.inArray should be Index, colindexes, instead of colindexes, index. Also I have added `>= 0` because inArray returns -1 when the element is not found.

```js
checkLocationTable([0, 2], 'table1')

function checkLocationTable(colindexes, tablename) {
  $("#" + tablename + " tr").each(function(index) {
    if ($.inArray(index, colindexes) >= 0) {
      $(this).find("td:eq(0) > input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked", true);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The Sizzle expression ends with `input[type='checkbox']` instead of `checkbox`.

Comment: So i must select the checkbox using the  "input ..."

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that. In your `$(this).find("td:eq(0) > checkbox")` you are looking for a tag name "checkbox". What you need is an input with type checkbox. So it is `input[type='checkbox']`. For selecting a class, it is ".myClass". Note the dot before myClass.

Comment: Well i though that if i use " checkbox" without any point it will select the element of type checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You put ".checkbox" in your javascript function, which finds element with class name checkbox, that might me the problem, try this :

```
function checkLocationTable (colindexes,tablename){
        var table = document.getElementById(tablename);
        for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
            if(colindexes.includes(i))
            {

                $(this).find("td:eq(0) checkbox").prop("checked",true);

            }
        }
    }
```

In your Jquery, inArray is given wrong, it should be like,

```
function checkLocationTable(colindexes,tablename)
{
     $("#"+tablename+" tr").each(function(index){ 
       if($.inArray(index,colindexes))
       {
          $(this).find("td:eq(0) > checkbox").prop("checked",true);
       }
  });
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: sorry, but where do you feed checkbox as a class here?

Comment: sorry, find* (not feed)